# Magento PWA modify contact us page

Tags: magento2, contact-us, pwa, pwa-studio

I have installed **pwa-studio** in my Magento version 2.4.3. Now I want to change design of **contact us** page also want to ad couple fields. I successfully modified header, footer, cms pages but can't seems to find way to override contact us page. Can anyone guide me how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: do you know how to clear the cache once we update in pwa component? i have tried to change in footer component but my changes is not reflected on frontend.

Comment: In local development mode you can run "yarn watch" and for production "yarn build"